# LINUX AWK command for a big file

Tags: awk

I have encountered a problem that exceeds my basic unix knowledge and would really appreciate some help. I have a large file in the following format:

```
chr1    10495   10499   211
chr1    10496   10500   1
chr1    10587   10591   93
chr1    10588   10592   1
chr1    10639   10643   4
chr1    10668   10672   11
chr1    10697   10701   13
chr1    10726   10730   8
chr1    10755   10759   7
chr1    10784   10788   5
chr2    10856   10860   4
chr3    10932   10936   6
chr3    10933   10937   2
chr5    11056   11060   4
chr6    11155   11159   9
```

If the values in column one match and one number difference in column two, I want to sum the values in column 4 of both lines and replace the value of column 3 in line 1 with the value of column 3 in line 2 , else just the the values in the unique line without modifying any column.

So the output I am hoping for would look like this:

```
chr1    10495   10500   212
chr1    10587   10592   94
chr1    10639   10643   4
chr1    10668   10672   11
chr1    10697   10701   13
chr1    10726   10730   8
chr1    10755   10759   7
chr1    10784   10788   5
chr2    10856   10860   4
chr3    10932   10937   8
chr5    11056   11060   4
chr6    11155   11159   9
```

Comment: Are the common values in column1 always grouped together and are the values in colum2 always ascending as shown in your sample input? Can you have 3 consecutive numbers in column2? If so, please edit your question to include that in your sample input/output so we can see how you want it handled. In any case, the answer will be an awk script - get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn how to manipulate text in UNIX.

Comment: What are you doing with the sum of the values in column 4?

Comment: Hi Morton,
yes the common values in column1 always group together and values in column2 are always ascending because i did sort. There are only 2 consecutive numbers in column 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
NR>1 {
    if ( ($1==p[1]) && ($2==(p[2]+1)) ) {
        print p[1], p[2], $3, p[4]+$4
        delete p[0]
        next
    }
    else if (0 in p) {
        print p[0]
    }
}
{ split($0,p); p[0]=$0 }
END { if (0 in p) print p[0] }
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
chr1    10495   10500   212
chr1    10587   10592   94
chr1    10639   10643   4
chr1    10668   10672   11
chr1    10697   10701   13
chr1    10726   10730   8
chr1    10755   10759   7
chr1    10784   10788   5
chr2    10856   10860   4
chr3    10932   10937   8
chr5    11056   11060   4
chr6    11155   11159   9
```

Comment: I think that `($1==p[1]) && ($2>=p[2]) && ($2<=p[3])` instead of `($1==p[1]) && ($2==(p[2]+1))` the instevals isn't always +1 that previous ....  although OP works well

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. the OP wants to check for `one number difference in column two`, so the interval IS always +1 and whatever is in `p[3]` is irrelevant, it's all about `$2/p[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't checked closely, but I think you want:

```
 awk '{split(p,a)} 
    $1==a[1] && a[2]==$2-1{print a[1], a[2], $3, $4 + a[4]; p=""; next}
     p {print p} {p=$0}
    END {print}' OFS=\\t input
```

At any given step (except the first), `p` holds the value from the previous line.  The 2nd line of the script checks if the first field in the current line matches the first field of the last line and that the 2nd field is one greater than the 2nd field of the last line.  In that condition, it prints the first two fields from the previous line, the third from the current line, and the sum of the 4th fields and moves on to the next line.  If they don't match, it prints the previous line.  At the end, it just prints the line.

Comment: Thanks William, 
It working almost perfect but fail to print last line. The output is :
chr1 10495 10500 212
chr1 10587 10592 94
chr1    10639   10643   4
chr1    10668   10672   11
chr1    10697   10701   13
chr1    10726   10730   8
chr1    10755   10759   7
chr1    10784   10788   5
chr2    10856   10860   4
chr3 10932 10937 8
chr5    11056   11060   4

Comment: @learner - no, it WILL print the last line. idk what you're doing wrong while running it. Only flaws I can see in the logic are: 1) because it doesn't skip the first line for the test, it would print the first line in the unlikely scenario where $1 was something that evaluated numerically to zero, and $2 was 1 less than the $2 on the 2nd line. Try it after adding a first line `0chr 10494 foo bar`. 2) It would duplicate the last line if that line has the same $1 and a $2 that's 1 more than the previous $2 - try it with with an additional line at the end that's `chr6 11156 11159 9`,

Answer (score 0):

This script, I'm using to merge intervals in transcriptome data

```
awk '
    NR==1{
        n= split($0, first);
        c=1;
        for(i=1; i<=n; i++) d[c, i] = first[i];
    }
    NR>1{
        n= split($0, actual);
        #if(actual[1] != d[c, 1] || actual[2]>d[c, 3]){  #for interval fusion
        if(actual[1] != d[c, 1] || actual[2]>d[c,2]+1){  #OP requirement
            c++;
            for(i=1; i<=n; i++) d[c, i] = actual[i];
       }else{
           if(actual[3] > d[c,3]) d[c,3] = actual[3];
           d[c,4] = d[c,4] + actual[4];
       }
   }
   END{
       for(i=1; i<=c; i++){
           print d[i, 1], d[i, 2], d[i, 3], d[i, 4]
       }
   }' file
```

you get:

```
chr1 10495 10500 212
chr1 10587 10592 94
chr1 10639 10643 4
chr1 10668 10672 11
chr1 10697 10701 13
chr1 10726 10730 8
chr1 10755 10759 7
chr1 10784 10788 5
chr2 10856 10860 4
chr3 10932 10937 8
chr5 11056 11060 4
chr6 11155 11159 9
```

Comment: You might want to rewrite that using GNU awk 4.* as it's true multi-D arrays will make your code briefer, more robust, and more easily extensible. e.g. the END section loop can be `for(i=1; i in d; i++){ for (j=1; j in d[i]; j++) ...` so it'll work for any number of fields. You don't need all those trailing semicolons that you've added to some lines and you don't need that 3rd arg for `split()` as the default value will do what you want.